# Why is this CSS3 transition timing sensitive?

Tags: css

Below is a short html file that includes all the css and almost all the javascript to do some transitions (it uses jquery from a cdn).  It's a little sandbox I'm playing with to see how all this stuff works.  What I've run into is that sometimes transitions don't happen.  This seems to be the case in FF4, Safari, and Chrome.  In FF4, the timeout sent to setTimeout has to be > 10, sometimes > 16, or it still fails.  Safari and Chrome seem to be OK with a timeout of 1.  Opera seems to not care what I do, it doesn't do this transition at all......

Is this an optimization bug in the browsers?  Or is this some misunderstanding that I have of transitions?  The transition in question is the one called pushLeft() which is triggered by the control "button" Push Left

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Transitions Effects Exercises</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type='text/css'>

    #slideShow {
        margin-top: 20px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .slide {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        /*padding: 20px;*/
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .push-left {
        -webkit-transition: left 10s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: left 10s ease-in;
        -o-transition: left 10s ease-in;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js' language="JavaScript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function reset() {
        $("#slide1").removeClass().addClass('slide');
        $("#slide2").removeClass().addClass('slide').css('opacity', 0);
    }

    function pushLeft2() {
        $("#slide2").addClass('push-left').css('left', 0);
    }
    function pushLeft() {
        var width = $('#slideShow').width();
        $("#slide2").css('left', width).css('opacity', 1);
        //$("#slide2").addClass('push-left').css('left', 0);  <- This line must run after setTimeout, or no transition happens in any of the browsers.
        setTimeout(pushLeft2, 1);
    }

    $(document).ready(reset);

</script>

<div>Controls  <a onclick='reset();'>Reset</a> <a onclick='pushLeft();'>Push Left</a></div>
<div id="slideShow">

    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <h2>This is Slide 1</h2>
        <p>This is the text on slide 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <h2>This is Slide 2</h2>
        <p>Slide 2 has different text</p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

for opera you have to write "all", opera don't accept all types of transition

```
 -o-transition: all 10s ease-in;
```

and for convention always add one without a kit

```
transition: left 10s ease-in;
```